# Can't apply inputSharpness on UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, filter, uiimage, ios5.1

I'm using a bunch of `CIFilter` filters in my app to adjust brightness, saturation etc' and they are working fine. I'm having some issues with `inputSharpness`. If I touch the sharpness slider the picture just disappears. Relevant code:

```
UIImage *aUIImage = [imageView image];
CGImageRef aCGImage = aUIImage.CGImage;
aCIImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:aCGImage];

//Create context
context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
sharpFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAttributeTypeScalar" keysAndValues: @"inputImage", aCIImage, nil];
```

....

```
- (IBAction)sharpSliderChanged:(id)sender
{

    //Set filter value
    [sharpFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sharpSlider.value] forKey:@"inputSharpness"];

    //Convert CIImage to UIImage
    outputImage = [sharpFilter outputImage];
    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);

    //add image to imageView
    [imageView setImage:newUIImage];

}
```

Comment: did u check if any of your outputImage is nil?

Comment: The image isn't nil but when I debug the code I see that `sharpFilter CIFilter * 0x00000000` So something is probably wrong with the sharp filter definition.

Comment: Do you retain your sharpFilter?

Comment: Yes. No change. After some reading I think that instead of `CIAttributeTypePosition` it should be `CIStripesGenerator` but then I get the error `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputImage.`

Comment: are u on ios 6? - see my anwser

Comment: no. ios 5. I won't limit my app to ios 6 just because this small feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read a post with a similar question, there a possible solution was to add a category for the UIImage effect you want to provide. The only difference here is that you should use one of the `CIColorControls` Parameters: `inputSharpness` and the `CISharpenLuminance` filter.

Back to your question: It seems from your comments you have some problem about how you initialize your filter. I take a look to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISharpenLuminance) and I would use `CISharpenLuminance` instead during the initialization phase. It is only available in ios 6 though.

**EDIT**
Like i said if you want to stick with core image the feature you want is available on iOS 6 only. I can recommend you to use a third party lib: [GPU library](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) from bradlarson if you want to be compatible with ios 5.

Comment: actually that article helped me with the other filters. Like I said above I won't limit my app to ios 6 just because this small feature. It will ios 5 minimum. After a lot of reading I'm starting to think that there is no sharpening filter to ios 5.